# Kivy + backend communication

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am new here.

I would like to ask for your help in frontend - backend communication in Kivy.

Both need to be in separate programs.

In Tkinter all I need to do:

gui:

```
import tkinter as tk
import backend_program as trans


class Gui():

    def __init__(self, backend):
        self._backend = backend

    def conversion(self):
        output_number = self._backend.gui_cumunication(input_number)

    def start(self):
        self.window.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    number = str()                            
    program = trans.ClassName(number)
    app = GuiTrans(program)
    app.start()
```

backend:

```
(...)
    def gui_cumunication(self, gui_input):
        self._arabic_number = gui_input
        self.split_number_and_put_into_list()
        self.check_if_in_range()
        message_to_gui = self.combine_roman_symbols_to_make_a_number()
        self._decimal_digits = []
        return message_to_gui
(...)
```

But when I try to do it in Kivy like this (or many other ways):

```
import kivy
import arabic_to_roman_numberals_converter as trans

class RomanGrid(Widget):
    
    def __init__(self, backend):
        self._backend = backend

    def get_number_from_user(self):
        self.number_to_convert = self.arabic_number.text
        print('Arabic number is:', self.number_to_convert)
        self.arabic_number.text = ''
        return self.number_to_convert

    def request(self):
        self.get_number_from_user()
        roman_number = self._backend

class RomanApp(App):

    def __init__(self, backend):
        self._backend = backend

    def build(self):
        return RomanGrid(self._backend)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    number = ''
    program = trans.Converter(number)
    RomanApp(program).run()

or 

class RomanApp(App):

    def __init__(self, backend):
        self._backend = backend

    def build(self):
        return RomanGrid()

    def start_app(self):
        RomanApp(self._backend).run()                


if __name__ == '__main__':
    number = ''
    program = trans.Converter(number)
    app = RomanApp(program)
    app.start_app()
```

Nothing is working and I get error like:

```
 AttributeError: 'RomanApp' object has no attribute 'built'
```

I don't know where to put the backend inside Kivy file.

Is there anybody who knows how to communicate kivy with separate program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you over-ride the `__init__()` method of a class that you are sub-classing (`RomanApp` and `RomanGrid` in your code), you must call the super `__init__()` method:

```
class RomanGrid(Widget):

    def __init__(self, backend):
        super(RomanGrid, self).__init__()
        self._backend = backend
```

and

```
class RomanApp(App):

    def __init__(self, backend):
        super(RomanApp, self).__init__()
        self._backend = backend
```